# three.js dont apply material

Tags: three.js, blender

I don't think my question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14732253/materials-in-exported-blender-model-for-three-js-not-working#),
but I have two unequal results in 
[blender render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWyDp.png) and
[three js generated scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Lqx8.png)

js code:

```js
let mesh;
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
const loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
const light = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x404040 ); // soft white light
light.position.x += 1;
light.position.z += 1;
scene.add(light);

camera.position.z = 5;

// scene.add(cube);
loader.load('untitled.json', function (geometry, material) {
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    console.log(mesh);
    scene.add(mesh);
})


renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    try {
        mesh.rotation.z += 0.001;
        mesh.rotation.x += 0.001;
    } catch(e){ }
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

animate();
```

Correspond to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17196516/threejs-cant-use-the-material-on-the-json-model-when-initializing-gives-me-web). I was [trying to UV unwrap model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFGQ2.png)
but, still can't figure out. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It seems like the problem has more to do with the model than with your code. Can you attach the `.blend` file?